# no method or default for coercing “dgeMatrix” to “unpackedMatrix”

Tags: r

When I was trying to run a robust linear mixed model(rlmer), I met a error whose content is 'Error in as(B, "unpackedMatrix") : no method or default for coercing “dgeMatrix” to “unpackedMatrix”'.

I'm wondering what the meaning is and how to solve it.
Supplementary infor: I run it successfully before. This time when I run the pacman::p_load(), some packages were updated automatically but some failed, and then is this problem. But I've already reinstalled all the related packages. So I'm not sure whether it's caused by any package.

Comment: Does it persist after running `install.packages(pkgs = installed.packages()[, 1])`? This will reinstall all packages currently on your system. The reason I ask is because this could be a version mismatch between the Matrix and lm4 packages. Matrix contains "dgeMatrix" whereas "unpackedMatrix" comes from lme4.

Comment: More specifically I would try `sapply(c("Matrix", "lme4", "robustlmm"), install.packages, type = "source")` - this should install packages *from source* in the right order ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. It works.